# How to correct type comparing in "if" construct

Tags: go, types

**I try to use "reflect" and "(type)"**

```
var a float64 = 6.0

if reflect.TypeOf(a) == float64 {
    fmt.Printf("%T", a)
}

switch a.(type) {
case float64:
    fmt.Printf("%T", a)
}
```

**but both returned errors**

error 1: type float64 is not an expression
error 2: cannot type switch on non-interface value a (type float64)

Comment: Don't post links, include the code in the question. And welcome to StackOverflow. `a.(type)` ain't gonna work because `a` is not an interface, `.(type)` works only on values of interface types. `TypeOf(a) == float64` ain't gonna work because `TypeOf` returns a value and `float64` is a type, a value is not a type, so `==` doesn't make sense, only `<value> == <value>` makes sense.

Comment: sorry my fault, I try to include image, not link, but I don`t now how(

Comment: Please take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) if the above doesn't click.

Comment: Don't include images and don't include links to images or code. You must include the code **as text**. Copy & paste.

Comment: Thank's. I hope now it` look better

Comment: Yes, much better, that is the correct way to include code in the question.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` statement can only compare to a single type because it doesn't have branches like the `switch` statement, and you have to use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) in an `if` statement like this:

```
var i interface{}
i = 3.3 // store a float64 value in i

if f, ok := i.(float64); ok {
    fmt.Print("It's a float64 value: %.2f", f)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Not float64")
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ws-6fgbnYcx)):

```
It's a float64 value: 3.30
```

You *could* use reflection too, but type assertion here is more efficient and more idiomatic. For reference, this is how using reflection would look like:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(i) == reflect.TypeOf(float64(0)) {
    fmt.Printf("It's a float64 value: %.2f", i)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Not float64")
}
```

Output is the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fZRQoUGd0GL).

Note that when we used type assertion, we had a variable `f` of the asserted type (`float64`) so we could use it if some function would require a value of that type directly. When using reflection, we did not have a value of such type, `i` is "still" of type `interface{}`, we could use it because `fmt.Printf()` takes values of `interface{}`. But if we would have to pass it to a function that requires `float64`, we would still need to use (an additional) type assertion, like in the first example.

Also note that using type assertion and a type switch only makes sense if your input is an interface type, because only interface types may store values of different / multiple concrete types.

Using type assertion or type switch on a concrete type (like `float64` value in your example) makes no sense becase that value may only be of type `float64` and nothing else, so the language spec doesn't allow it in the first place.